# Как сделать passwordbox как в html?

Tags: c++, winapi

Делаю программу на чистом c++ winapi дошёл до части регистрации пользователя. И встал вопрос о том как реализовать placeholder  для поля пароля. Пытался через добавление стиля к полю  во время нажатия на него, но почему то это у меня не работает.

P.S. сторонние библиотеки использовать нельзя

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/controls/em-setcuebanner?redirectedfrom=MSDN https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-RU/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-edit_setcuebannertext

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков спасибо вам огромное! Это помогло